# How to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, datetime

My code is:

```
    lblbilldate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(lblbilldate);
    lblbilldate.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date);
```

In above coding i took system date in lblbilldate and i want to convert the date into dd/MM/yyyy format. 
But i got following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: Please [**tag**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question with the programming language and/or framework you're using, preferably as the first tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert it like this it like this

```
lblbilldate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(lblbilldate.Text);
```

you were using `lblbilldate` which is denoting the label you need its text `lblbilldate.Text`

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to convert the label to a datetime but its content:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(lblbilldate.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert label text and not label on the whole.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(lblbilldate.Text);
```